# How to download a file through a rest call with a jwt token using angular

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, jwt

I'm using the following snippet, which works on POSTMAN using a Bearer token, to let a user download a certain file.

It uses a REST call to a spring boot rest controller.

```
downloadCSV(id){
    const download_link = this.baseUrl + "csvfiles/" + id;
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    this.http.get(download_link, token )
      .pipe(
        tap(data => this.baseUrl)
        ,catchError(this.handleError('downloadCSV catchError: ', download_link))
      );
  }
```

When I call this function a new tab pops up on the browser saying "denied access", because the call happens in a new tab and I'm clearly not passing the token there.

(This function was working before we implemented the JWT security login)